# Difference between types of object creation in javascript

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between

```
var obj = new factoryCreation;
```

and

```
var obj = new factoryCreation();
```

in javascript.

Are these one and the same??
Assume `factoryCreation` is a function.

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) says:

> new Foo is equivalent to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called without arguments.